# .NET 5.0 - Angular 9 - MVC regex not validating double value

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, validation

I am having trouble validating a **double** field provided from an angular form

I send **50.5** in the field **FacialValue** and the regex is **^[+]?\d+([.]\d{1,2})?$** (checked in regex101)

here is my field definition:

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(Tools.AmountValidator, ErrorMessage = "Some characters are not allowed")]
public double FacialValue { get; set; }
```

here I debug the modelstate to see which field is causing issue

```
foreach (var errorDetails in errors)
{
    foreach (ModelError error in modelState[errorDetails.key].Errors)
    {
        Tools.log("field '" + errorDetails.key + "' has error : " + error.ErrorMessage, true, null, telemetry, logger, context);
    }
}
```

which leads to these key/error

```
errorDetails.key = "Lead.Opportunities[0].FacialValue"
error.ErrorMessage = "Some characters are not allowed"
```

here is what I send in angular :

[image]

Any help appreciated, I just dont get it, this should work

Comment: Can you share how you pass data from angular to mvc?I test with `[RegularExpression("^[+]?\\d+([.]\\d{1,2})?$", ErrorMessage = "Some characters are not allowed")]`,50.5 is valid.

Comment: it's in the screenshot, yes indeed, this was working with .NET Core 3.1

Comment: I test in .net 5,`[RegularExpression("^[+]?\\d+([.]\\d{1,2})?$", ErrorMessage = "Some characters are not allowed")]` can work.

Comment: I dont know what's the issue, I did not change my validation

Comment: public const string AmountValidator = @"^[+]?\d+([.]\d{1,2})?$";